# Confusion about device-width difference in meta tags and media queries

Tags: android, css, mobile

I'm working on getting my website to work on different mobile devices and I've come across a couple problems with device-width. I know questions like this have been asked before but I've read conflicting things both here and elsewhere and haven't found anything that clarifies what I'm looking for.

Assume I'm using a Nexus One which has a resolution of 480x800. Now if make a meta tag like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

If it is in portrait the viewport width is 320px and if it is in landscape the viewport width is 533px. This makes sense as the logical resolution is 320x533. But when I make a media query like:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
    /*CSS rules here */
}
```

The device-width refers to physical resolution and doesn't change based on orientation. So for the Nexus One the device-width is 480px regardless of orientation and therefore isn't included in the media query.

Is this normal behavior? If it is, why does device-width behave so differently between the two? They're using not only different values but one of them changes based on orientation and the other doesn't. This is very confusing and to make things worse I've read the exact opposite( that media query device-width is affected by orientation and meta tag device-width is not)  other places on the web.

Any help clarifying would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘device-width’ media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device. For continuous media, this is the width of the screen. For paged media, this is the width of the page sheet size.

I'm not an expert on  mobile web design, but I think orientation doesnt affect to the device-width values.

[You can read more about media queries here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)